# How to convert data with k and M at the end back to numbers in json array

Tags: javascript

I am getting data from an API in jso format but one of the element is giving values in k and M instead of thousand and million.
how can I convert it back to number.

```
k = [
    {'stock_change_volume' : '169.2 K'},
    {'stock_change_volume' : '69.2 K'},
    {'stock_change_volume' : '169.2 M'}
]
```

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var k = [
{
'stock_change_volume' : '169.2 K'
},
{
'stock_change_volume' : '69.2 K'
},
{
'stock_change_volume' : '169.2 M'
}
];

for(var i of k){
  console.log(getVal(i['stock_change_volume']));
}

function getVal (val) {
  var value = val.substr(-1).toLowerCase();
  if (value == "k")
    return parseFloat(val) * 1000;
  else if (value == "m")
    return parseFloat(val) * 1000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```